# How to alert ajax response on complete

Tags: jquery, post, response

I am sending POST request

```
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : 'https://123.com/test.php',
   data: {json: json, id: id, token: token, number: num},
   xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
   complete : function(data){                   
                alert( "Status: " + data.responseText );
   },
});
```

Post request is working and when i look at chrome console i can see response is "success", but i cant display it .

I have tryed

```
data.responseText
```

and

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data)
```

and

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

I always get empty alert box

Answer (score 2):

you can try below, ( if you don't want to use ajax `success` )

```
complete: function(event,xhr,options) {
  alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

- event - contains the event object
- xhr - contains the XMLHttpRequest object
- options - contains the options used in the AJAX request

Comment: When i do this , i dont even get response, i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

complete executes after either the success or error callback were executed.

**success**

> The function gets passed two arguments: The data returned from the
>   server, formatted according to the 'dataType' parameter, and a string
>   describing the status.

**complete**

> The function gets passed two arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object and
>   a string describing the type of success of the request.

So if you replace `complete` with `success` you also have to replace `data.responseText` with `data` only.

Try below one

```
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : 'https://123.com/test.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {json: json, id: id, token: token, number: num},
   xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
   success : function(data){                   
                console.log(data);
   },
});
```

If you need to have access to the whole XMLHttpRequest object in the success callback I suggest trying this.

```
var myXHR = $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data, status) {

    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Also could be CORS problem on top of this since `withCredentials` is only needed for cross domain requests

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah i am doing cross domain request and i ve actaully got an error in conosle saying : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://123.com/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @MHB if you control the endpoint then you need to implement CORS in that php script. Do a search on that error...will find thousands of results

Comment: @charlietfl i do not control the endpoint , anything else i can do ? Its funny because i can see response in chrome console and cant get it into alert box. Whats the deal ?

Comment: Do the search and understand what CORS is. Not all API's are ajax accessible and sometimes require using proxies